# assign mutiple variable in for-each loop

Tags: xml, variables, xslt

I want to set multiple variable value in loop using xslt. my xml Example is,

```
<details>
<person>
    <name>abcd</name>
    <age>24</age>
</person>
<person>
    <age>27</age>
    <name>xyz</name>
</person>
```

I want to store name and age in two different variable e.g

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="details">

    <xsl:variable name="name"/>
    <xsl:variable name="age"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="./person">
        // want to store name and age in two different variable for later use after for-each loop
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>     
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It's just an example xml and xslt. Is anyone know, how to do this ?

Comment: Can you explain why you think you need to store those values?

Comment: XSLT doesn't work like this.  If you can give an example of _what_ you actually need to achieve rather than _how_ you think you want to achieve it then someone will be able to suggest a different approach that's a better fit with XSLT's functional programming style.

Answer (score 0):

**Q.:** *"Is anyone know, how to do this ?"*

Short answer: I is not possible to change the value of a variable after declaration. Also it is not possible to access an variable which is declared in a "block" (e.g xsl:for-each) outside of this "block".